# adding new properties in expando object in foreach loop

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I have to add new properties in expando object in foreach loop but I am not able to see a way to do it. Here is the example:

var allProperties = new List { "Name", "Email", "Roles" };
allProperties.AddRange(metaDataModel.GetFormattedFolders());

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var s in allProperties)
{
    expando.s = string.Empty;
}
```

It consider 's' as a property instead of considering value of 's' as property name.

Thanks

Comment: What type of object is `expando`?

Comment: It is Dynamic:   dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var expando = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
foreach (var s in allProperties)
{
    expando.Add(s, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: above does not work. It says:Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

Comment: Thanks. It works. Not sure why we have to cast it into IDictionary object to acheive this?

Comment: ExpandoObject is IDictionary<string,object> underneath but you can't use indexing with`[]` or adding properties like we do with normal Collections.